# Plesk failed to upgrade on centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, opensuse, plesk

I am unable to upgrade existing Plesk 12.4 update 23 on centos 6.7.
The log shows that the upgrade script is trying to fetch data from a non-existing folder in opensuse repository. Have some faced this situation with plesk? i just simply dont understand why it is trying a folder related to older version of centos (5)?  how can i fix this. The log reads like this:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile


* base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server%3A/mail/CentOS_5/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Failed to install plesk-l10n:
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. For a question to be accepted on these sites, the OP must display some good will in detailing what has been tried, and what has failed, in trying to address a given question. What do you make of the output? Have you searched thru Google for the error message you received? have you tried any of the solutions available online? If they failed, how did they fail?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be corrupted Yum cache. Can you please try **"yum clear all"** and see if it helps? 
Source : http://kb.plesk.com/en/124973

Answer (score 0):

It was an unused repo that was creating this issue. 'Server:mail.repo' referring to non-existing url was actually leftover from some previous package. I just removed it and Yum is doing all good.

To check what package is using a repo (server:mail.repo in my case) :

> rpm -df /etc/yum.repos.d/server:mail.repo

It shown than no package was using it. I than simply removed it.

Hope it helps someone with similar situation. Regards